# How to format a float as integer when .toFixed(2) gives zeros after the decimal point?

Tags: javascript, numbers, number-formatting

I wonder what would be the shortest and safest way to achieve the following:

Suppose I have a float var with the value `1.200123`. In our visualization, I want to show this value with two decimal places, so I use `myFloat.toFixed(2);` at the moment, which gives me `1.20`.

That's fine. But what if the resulting output only has zeros at the decimal places? For example the value `1.000043` which becomes `1.00`.

For the case above: how can I omit the decimal point and the zeros and just get `1` as output, preferrably without parsing and manipulating the string that comes out of `.toFixed(2)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ...preferrably without parsing and manipulating the string that comes out of .toFixed(2)?

Well, you **could** do it numerically, though I'd worry about getting a perfect match between numeric logic and [`toFixed`'s logic](https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number.prototype.tofixed), given the definition of `toFixed` includes phrases like:

> Let *n* be an integer for which the exact mathematical value of *n* ÷ 10<sup>*f*</sup> - *x* is as close to zero as possible. If there are two such *n*, pick the larger *n*.

So I'd probably just update the string, it's not a lot of work:

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
    return num.toFixed(2).replace(/\.00$/, "");
}

function test(num) {
    console.log(num, "=>", formatNumber(num));
}
test(1.01);
test(1.43);
test(23.7);
test(1.200123);
test(1.000043);
test(1.007);
test(1.0007);
```

But here's an approximate numeric approach, which at least matches the results for the test cases above:

```js
function formatNumber(num) {
    var check = Math.round(num * 100) / 100;
    var rounded = Math.round(check);
    if (rounded == check) {
        return String(rounded);
    }
    return num.toFixed(2);
}

function formatNumberViaToFixed(num) {
    return num.toFixed(2).replace(/\.00$/, "");
}

function test(num) {
    var formatted = formatNumber(num);
    var viaToFixed = formatNumberViaToFixed(num);
    if (formatted == viaToFixed) {
        console.log(num, "=>", formatted);
    } else {
        console.log(num, "=>", formatted, "ERROR: Should be", viaToFixed);
    }
}
test(1.01);
test(1.43);
test(23.7);
test(1.200123);
test(1.000043);
test(1.007);
test(1.0007);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, T.J.! Is this "locale-safe" when there are other characters than the "." as a decimal point? That's what I had been thinking of when trying to avoid working with a string.

Comment: @Robert - Yes, `toFixed` is not locale-aware: https://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-number.prototype.tofixed If it were, though, you could use `.replace(/\D00/, "")` instead, on the basis that anything non-digit there is going to be a decimal point. :-)

Comment: While i'm fine with the RegExp approach (it is performant and i wouldn't worry about locales), i am wondering about the math approach - did you ever try it? I suggest to either fix or remove it, otherwise in future people would c&p it and come back to SO asking why it's not working :)

Comment: @wiesion - I did, though certainly not thoroughly, along these lines: http://jsfiddle.net/zn0ytkpc/ What's broken? I agree wholeheartedly about either fixing or removing. (Although people doing blind C&P get what they deserve. :-) ) Thanks in advance.

Comment: OP was asking for `1.200123` => `1.20` and `1.000043` => `1` - it was about making an int by ignoring the floating value after a certain digit - your regex does that, but the math approach does not (it gives `1.00` for `1.000043`)

Comment: @wiesion - It was handling 1.200123 correctly, but thank you for the 1.000043 example! When I was doing it, I had a feeling something was wrong, but didn't test a number that showed the problem. I appreciate your flagging this up, thanks! Fixed now (I hope).

Comment: Almost there :) Use `floor`, with `round` you would get `1.007` => `1.01`

Comment: @wiesion - `1.01` is correct for `1.007`. `(1.007).toFixed(2)` is `1.01`. `toFixed` rounds, it doesn't truncate.

Comment: Yes that's true, but now i am wondering what OP wanted to have in such cases, since in his example he was not specifying if the digit removal was to be done after toFloat or before

Comment: But if it's the latter then it's working perfectly fine now - while mine won't because of `trunc` :)

Comment: @wiesion - Well, even if the OP wants to go one way, perhaps someone else will want to go another and your solution will help them! :-)

Comment: True enough, so let's call it a day about this question - it was a nice constructive convo :)

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Number(myFloat.toFixed(2))`.

While this produces a value with type `number` rather than `string`, you can use it in a string expression (implicitly calling its `.toString()` method), or call `.toString()` explicitly, to produce the string format you want.

As `Number.toString()` does no special formatting, converting the string to a number and then back removes trailing zeroes from rounded value produced by `.toFixed()`.

The downside of this method would be that it converts `1.10` to `"1.1"` rather than `"1.10"`, which may or may not be what you want for your visualisation.

Comment: I haven't thought of that, interesting approach!

Answer (score 3):

I would create this conditional `toFixed` method within the `Number` prototype, which in the end will call the `this.toFixed` method so that you will keep that original behavior and only adjust the amount of digits passed to it - that can be easily done with `Math.pow` and `Math.trunc`.

```js
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'toConditionalFixed', {
  enumerable: false,
  writable: false,
  configurable: false,
  value: function(digits) {
    let comp = Math.pow(10, digits);
    return this.toFixed(Math.trunc(this * comp) % comp === 0 ? 0 : digits);
  }
});


console.log(
  (1.200123).toConditionalFixed(2),
  '|',
  (1.200123).toConditionalFixed(3),
  '|',
  (1.200123).toConditionalFixed(4),
  '|',
  (1.000043).toConditionalFixed(2),
  '|',
  (1.000043).toConditionalFixed(3),
  '|',
  (1.000043).toConditionalFixed(4),
  '|',
  (1.000043).toConditionalFixed(5)
);
```

**EDIT**

For the sake of completeness, the same method within `Number.prototype` which works with RegExp:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'toConditionalFixed', {
  enumerable: false,
  writable: false,
  configurable: false,
  value: function(digits) {
    let re = new RegExp("\\." + "0".repeat(digits)  + "$");
    return this.toFixed(digits).replace(re, "");
  }
});

console.log(
  (1.200123).toConditionalFixed(2),
  '|',
  (1.200123).toConditionalFixed(3),
  '|',
  (1.200123).toConditionalFixed(4),
  '|',
  (1.000043).toConditionalFixed(2),
  '|',
  (1.000043).toConditionalFixed(3),
  '|',
  (1.000043).toConditionalFixed(4),
  '|',
  (1.000043).toConditionalFixed(5)
);
```

Comment: Underrated answer. Thank you.